# $.ajax call works, $http.get() does not (404, not found)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to replace my `$.ajax` call with `$http.get()`. I get a 404 Not Found error when I try.

Here is the ajax call:

```
    //  ToDo: See if there is an $http.get equivalent. That way the callback doesn't have
    //        to be wrapped in $scope.apply().
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PrestoWeb/api/ping/responses/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(latestPingRequest),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (responses) {
            // do stuff
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

And this is the $http call:

```
    var config = {
        url: '/PrestoWeb/api/ping/responses/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(latestPingRequest),
        contentType: "application/json"
    };

    $http.get(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            // do stuff
        }, function (response) {
            alert(response);
    });
```

The ajax call works. The http call does not. The URL, type, and data are the exact same in both calls. What am I missing?

Comment: You realize, `$http.get` with `method: post` is contradicting, right?

Comment: You are making a post in the original $.ajax call.  Do you want to make a POST or a GET?  If post, then you should use $http.post(config)

Comment: I tried $http.post(config) and I get the same 404 error.

Comment: It's [`$http(config)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: These downvoters are ridiculous.  Why the downvotes?  If it is because the OP didn't know to use $.post instead of $.get it is because he clearly presented his code and the problems he was having with it.  Seems like a good question to me

Comment: `$http.post()` and `$http.get()` are shortcut methods. The first argument should be a URL. You don't even need the config object, because Angular will do those things for you: `$http.post(url, data);`

Comment: `$http.post(url, data, config)`. Also the $http module automatically stringifies for you, so you don't need to be doing that yourself. edit yes as @SunilD. says, you likely just need `$http.post(url, { some: 'data' })`

Comment: This is a simple case of using a well documented method incorrectly. The fact is the way he is using it simply isn't creating the same request that the ajax method is. Forget the fact that it works with $.ajax, look at the requirements for the request, and follow the documentation. If it doesn't work correctly, open the network tab and figure out what it did differently.

Comment: You know, if I was already an expert on this stuff, I wouldn't need to ask. Some of you know this stuff so well that it seems like this is a silly question. I'm glad I asked. I learned something and got my code working. Thanks to those who helped.

Comment: @KevinB a misunderstanding of a well-documented feature in and of itself doesn't make it a bad question.  If I can't find a reason to close this question (and I can't), I disagree with the premise that it should be voted down.

Comment: I never said it was a bad question, i downvoted for lack of research, not because it is documented, but because no information on the request from the network tab was included (which would have of course made the question... pointless.)

Comment: @KevinB It's difficult to assess the amount of research that was done before this question was asked.  That said, although lack of researched USED to be a reasonable downvote reason before, I'd argue that in today's current SO environment, that's no longer a reason: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down . I certainly wouldn't describe this as a "no-effort" post.

Comment: Since I'm still learning and people are still looking at this post, perhaps someone can be kind enough to tell answer something else for me. I just tried changing my request to a GET and the data sent to the Web API is null. If I change it back to POST, the data is valid. Anyone?

Comment: when you send JSON Stringified data via the body with a method of GET, the server might be ignoring the body and just looking for querystring params. depends on server implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use GET because I'm getting data from the server. But perhaps I need to use POST because I'm including data in the request?

Comment: usually you do want to use POST when you want to *send* data to the server, and GET when you want to *get* data from the server. but, that's not set in stone, you could of course send data to the server using GET too, if the server knows how to read it (or you use url params)

Comment: And btw Kevin, I did some research. I spent 30 minutes trying to get this working, and I pulled up many pages on it. Based on one web page (that I no longer have open) I thought it was acceptable to do $http.get() with the method being POST. I was wrong. This isn't my area of expertise.

Comment: So should I be doing a GET or a POST in my case? Ultimately, I'm getting data, but I'm also sending data as a parameter.

Comment: I would go with GET, if the purpose is getting data. that would mean sending your json within a url parameter, or breaking it down into url parameters instead of json (or, just send it as json in the body if the server is setup to read it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem you are having is using `$http.get` instead of `$http.post`.  The $http object has some helper methods for the common http verbs, e.g. $http.get, $http.post, $http.put which will set the method to the name of the shorthand. The helper method for post expects three parameters, a url, your data and a configuration object so your call would look like, `$http.post('/PrestoWeb/api/ping/responses/', latestPingRequest, config)`

In your case you specify `method: 'POST'` in your http configuration object but then use the `$http.get` method, which will make a get request instead of what you specified in your configuration object.

Because you specified the method in your configuration object, you could just use `$http(config)` and skip the helper methods entirely.  I actually prefer doing things this way as your full request is defined in the configuration object and not the configuration object and method used.  The helper methods also all have different signatures which is confusing.  Easier just to stick to the $http(config) IMO

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful! I learned something, and that's what SO is supposed to be about.